# I want to display data stored in mysql database in .html file on input boxes,tables,or in a div using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I am able to connect to the database using node.js and retrieve data from database using handlebars but not able to send data using .html extension. Any method as far as it gets saved in .html extension will work for me.
this is my handlebars file:-

```
<table class="table " id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Sr.Number</th>
      <th>Quote</th>
      <th>Author</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     {{#each results}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ id }}</td>
      <td>{{ quote }}</td>
      <td>{{ author}}</td>

    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my .js file which connects database and sets view engine as hbs and it also passes a mysql query to select all items of database:-

```
    const path = require('path');
    const express = require('express');
    const hbs = require('hbs');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const app = express();

    const conn = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'password',
      database: 'theblog'
    });
    conn.connect((err) =>{
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log('Mysql Connected...');
    });

    //set views file
    app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
    //set view engine
    app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    //set public folder as static folder for static file
    app.use('/public',express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

    //route for homepage
    app.get('/',(req, res) => {
      let sql = "SELECT * FROM quote_gall";
      let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('quote',{
          results: results

             });
      });
    });

      app.listen(2121);
      console.log("Running at Port 2121");
```

I am expecting help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to use handlebar and html both side by side?

Comment: no just html file to render mysql data

Answer (score 0):

write sql! you can use 'insert' command.

```
let sql = "INSERT INTO *TABLE_NAME* (calumn1, calumn2, calumn3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)";
conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    //~
}
```

you can use that query if you want to add data.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I want to render mysql data in .html file.create,update and delete is done but for displaying I have to use .hbs file which I dont want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **consolidate** and **swig**

```
npm install consolidate
npm install swig
```

add these lines in above file:

```
var cons = require('consolidate');

// view engine setup
app.engine('html', cons.swig)
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Comment: <tr>
              <th>Sr.Number</th>
              <th>Quote</th>
              <th>Author</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
             {{#each results}}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ id }}</td>
              <td>{{ quote }}</td>
              <td>{{ author}}</td>

            </tr>                                                                                                                     what about binding data in html file

Comment: i am not getting it?

Comment: the table tag in the html file above binding is done through handlebars and I want to do same using method that would not change .html extension